# In spring security oauth, What is the default duration of refresh token?

Tags: java, spring-security-oauth2

What is the default duration of the oauth refresh token in a spring application?

I want to know the **default** value, so we don't have to set the value ourselves or provide a parameterized ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it in the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.java) after all:

The resource token is valid for 30 days:

```
private int refreshTokenValiditySeconds = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30; // default 30 days.
```

The accessToken is valid for 12 hours:

```
private int accessTokenValiditySeconds = 60 * 60 * 12; // default 12 hours.
```

---

**OLD ANSWER:**

I don't know from the top of my head but you can easily find out using the `getAccessTokenValiditySeconds();` method as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.html#getAccessTokenValiditySeconds(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Request)).